# Device Token not received when registering for remote notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I somehow can not receive the device token when registering for remote notifications. I get the modal saying "Do you want to allow App X to be able to send you notificaitons", but when I accept it, the didRegisterForRemoteNotifications function is not called.

When I register for remote notifications in iOS 8/Swift using this code:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

These functions are not triggered at all:

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!)
```

and

```
func application(application: UIApplication,    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!)
```

however when I log this

```
println("current settings \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()) and \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications())")
```

I receive

```
"current settings <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x170437120; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);> and true"
```

My provisioning profile and certificates ar all in order.

Has someone else had this problem?

Comment: Why do you call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` twice?

Comment: 1) create push notification and attach with your profile                  
2) on in capabilities push notification       
3) Send device token
see more to down my answer is there

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
            UIUserNotificationType.Sound

        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        var characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")

        var deviceTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
            .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "") as String

        println(deviceTokenString)

    }
```

**EDIT: Update for Swift 2.x**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
```

**EDIT: Update for Swift 3.x**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.description.trimmingCharacters(in: characterSet).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "");
    print(deviceTokenString)
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work! Could it have something to do with a certificate?

Comment: yes, what you need to do, create again from scratch.

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970840/device-token-not-received-on-ipad" could you able to find answer for this question I tried with your answers but it doesn't work for iPad

Comment: it's problem on device token in swift 3

Comment: what are you doing different from the OP's code? What's wrong with doing : `UIApplication.sharedApplication()`?

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3.0 you can use:

```
let deviceTokenString = message.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
```

Answer (score 3):

For swift 4.0 please follow some steps :

1).On push notification in capabilities(TARGET)

2).Use this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
  let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

3).Add this also

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }

    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your certificates are valid and app is registered successfully,Do some Googling and u will sure find right way.This code worked for me.

(in AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method )

```
var notify : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:UIUserNotificationType.Alert|UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notify)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

// Add Delegate methods of UIApplication

```
   func application(application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData){
 //send this device token to server

    println("\(deviceToken)")
}
```

//Called if unable to register for APNS.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

    println(error)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5

For Swift 5, I have used like this,

```
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: it is deprecated in ios10, use requestAuthorization method of UNUserNotificationCenter now.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this message, then you have already registered and the method will get called only when the application gets launched or the token gets changed. It has slight chance that the token will be updated.

Probably, you can try to delete the application from you test device and try to clear it from Xcode. And do it over again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I already tried that and tried it on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

When `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` doesn't get called, you should always first reconnect to another Wi-Fi network, or toggle Flight modus twice, and restart your app, before you try anything else. Otherwise restarting your device may also help.