# Send remote push notification to specific user

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I created a code to send remote notification using APNs, I created a development  certificate, ssl, etc. The code worked very well, when I call my php script on my server, the script send a notification and my app on my iPhone show the notification.
But I have a doubt, this is a generic code, so this code will send a nofication to all iphones that has my app, but if I need to send a notification to a specific user? Like whatsapp for example? How can I inform to APNs what user that should receive the notification?

Comment: On your server side you should differ your users by device and rest token. So while registering ios app for apns, app should send both tokens to server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need either a new table to handle the user_id and its device token or add a column to the user table for device token. When you send a push notification, you can then send directly to the user device token which alert the user.

Some steps that you need to prepare will be a api endpoint to allow user to `PUT` or `POST` its device token to its account. Maybe something like `api/v1/user/11/token`. In your iOS side, you will then just call this endpoint to send the device token to the endpoint when the permission is accept.

I would suggest a separate table to handle the token because some user have different device like android and iOS. So if you want to alert both devices, is will be a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Get device token while registering for push notification, send that device token via API to server, then using that device token you would be able to target push notificaion to particular devices only.

Refer - [Device Token not received when registering for remote notifications in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012420/device-token-not-received-when-registering-for-remote-notifications-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks by help. This link helped